# ERROR: Caused by: Unknown XML node, expected "testExecutions" but got "testsuite" at line 1 by sonar run for NodeJs application

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, mocha.js, sonarqube-scan, nyc

my sonar project template

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths = unit_test_results.xml 
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths = unit_test_results.xml
```

my package.json includes

```
"test": "nyc --all --reporter=text --reporter=lcov _mocha --recursive --reporter=xunit --reporter-options output=unit_test_results.xml src/** controller/**",
```

The output file looks like

```
<testsuite name="Mocha Tests" tests="1840" failures="0" errors="2" skipped="8" timestamp="Mon, 18 Oct 2021 11:39:52 GMT" time="16.335">
<testcase classname="xxxxxxxxxx" name="xxxxxxxxx" time="0.011"/>
<testcase classname="yyyyyyyyyy" name="yyyyyyyyyyy" time="0.001"/>
</testsuite>
```

When sonar is running getting below error

```
2021-10-18T10:11:09.5161270Z       1 INFO: Parsing /runner/_work/yy/yy/unit_test_results.xml
2021-10-18T10:11:09.5162390Z       1 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-10-18T10:11:09.5163293Z       1 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
2021-10-18T10:11:09.5164400Z       1 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-10-18T10:11:09.5165097Z       1 INFO: Total time: 9.105s
2021-10-18T10:11:09.5165893Z       1 INFO: Final Memory: 18M/527M
2021-10-18T10:11:09.5166873Z       1 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-10-18T10:11:09.9107082Z       1 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
2021-10-18T10:11:09.9113544Z       1 ERROR: Error during parsing of generic test execution report '/runner/_work/yy/yy/unit_test_results.xml'. Look at the SonarQube documentation to know the expected XML format.
2021-10-18T10:11:09.9118281Z       1 ERROR: Caused by: Unknown XML node, expected "testExecutions" but got "testsuite" at line 1
```

seems like i need to convert my unit_test_results.xml file to the below format. is that possible

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testExecutions version="1">
  <file path="<long path>/__tests__/api.test.js">
    <testCase name="Feature when called with proper params then does somthing" duration="5"/>
    <testCase name="Feature when called with wrong paramg then does nothing" duration="1"/>
  </file>
</testExecutions>
```